# The easiest way to extract text with paragrahps <p> using Jsoup in Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to get a text from html but with paraghrapsh `<p></p>` which means new line. I can do it only by converting Jsoup element to String and splitting it. Is there easier solution?

Using Jsoup.select:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html>" +
                                        "<body>" +
                                            "<div>" +
                                                "<h1>Example Domain</h1>" +
                                                    "<p>bla bla FIRST LINE blabla</p>" +
                                                    "<p>bla bla SECOND LINE blabla</p>" +
                                            "</div>" +
                                        "</body>" +
                                    "</html>");


        Element el = doc.select("div").first();
        System.out.println(el.text());
    }

}
```

it prints:

```
Example Domain bla bla bla FIRST LINE blablabla bla bla bla SECOND LINE blablabla
```

but I want:

```
<h1>Example Domain</h1>
<p>bla bla FIRST LINE blabla</p>
<p>bla bla SECOND LINE blabla</p>
```

or:

```
<h1>Example Domain</h1><p>bla bla FIRST LINE blabla</p><p>bla bla SECOND LINE blabla</p>
```

or:

```
Example Domain
bla bla FIRST LINE blabla
bla bla SECOND LINE blabla
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `.html()` should do it:

```
System.out.println(el.html());
```